# Android 12 - Activity Recognition With broadcast receiver in background not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, activity-recognition

I am trying to get user activity states by `ActivityRecognition` API and it works in foreground and for few hours in background too (When user exit the app) but after more than 4/5 hours it stop sending user activity states by `ActivityRecognition` API.

Setup Activity Recognition and Registering BroadcastReceiver In Main Activity

```
public static void ActivityRecognitionSetup() {
        final String TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION = "com.example.TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION";
        Intent mintent = new Intent(TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION);

        ActivityRecognitionClient client = ActivityRecognition.getClient(context);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (App_Functions.runningSOrLater){
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Application.getmContext(), 255, mintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        }else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApplication.getmContext(), 255, mintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
        ActivityRecognitionBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new ActivityRecognitionBroadcastReceiver();

         Task<Void> task = client.requestActivityUpdates(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
            task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Activity recognition Started");
                    context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION));
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Activity recognition Failed");
                }
            });
    }
```

Also Registering BR in Manifest

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".ActivityRecognitionBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class ActivityRecognitionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   
    final String TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION ="com.example.TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!TextUtils.equals(TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION, intent.getAction())) {            
            return;
        }
        
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            // This Method Will Show Notification On Every Activity Recognition Detection
            showNotification("Activity Recognition "+activity.getConfidence(),result.getProbableActivities())
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "ActivityRecognition Has NO Result "+ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent));
        }
    }

}
```

Even on idle the device is getting notifications but after 4-5 hours or sometimes more it stop receiving any broadcast from activity recognition api. Any ideas why this happening?

Comment: you need to use work manager for that

Comment: @ParthLotia For registering BR or Activity Manager ?

Comment: @androidXP have you got resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with a new update, but after a deeper debugging I realised that it actually works but it takes more time to retrieve data, so just be patient or run for longer time

Comment: I am running this for months.It stop working in background and stop detecting the user activities.

Comment: did you use         return START_STICKY; for you services ?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing i tried after testing it's working in foreground